# Implementing spreadsheet functionality (auto updating variables) in compiled code

Tags: c#, spreadsheet

I need a place in my code where variables auto-update when other variables change that they are dependent on.

The difference from spreadsheets is I don't want all the parsing stuff, I just want everything done in code as I don't need to update formulas/variables after the program has been compiled.

Basically there is input data, and a few "cells" from the spreadsheet part will listen in on those values, change, and the change will propagate through the "spreadsheet" part. Like a normal spreadsheet.

So I can then immediately after depend on all those values, instead of having to write all kinds of code to update all the variables correctly first, which would be very hard to do.

If anyone can help me with the thought process to implement this it would really help! I've been reading some spreadsheet source code but it will take a long time to understand that, and then understand how I would change those ideas to fit what I need to do.

Edit: 
Right now I just have things in loops and structure everything correctly so it updates correctly like so:

```
A1 = 2;
B1 = A1 + 2;
```

Then this just loops again and again. But if I wanted things to update automatically, how would I store the calculations attached to the variables? So when updating B it would call A1 + 2 ?

By the way A1, and B1 are just random variables. I don't name things by cell names and there is no such structure.

Comment: First thing you will need to consider is calculating cell dependencies .That is, which cells have no dependencies, cells that depend on those, and cells that depends on ones with dependencies and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Taylor. Please check my edit, I have added a question. I'm wondering how I store the calculations that the "cells" will then call to recalculate themselves.

Comment: Well, that's why having a parser (even internally) will help. You'll have the ability to calculate and see the dependencies with your formulas

Comment: If you don't use a parser you'll need to store the dependencies and have separate code for each cell to calculate it's value

Comment: Ahh I see! Now things are much clearer :) That's sort of what I was afraid of but I don't yet have the whole programmers view of things since I am just beginning, so I wasn't sure about this.

Comment: It really depends on how complex your formulas are, how many there and how often you're likely to want to change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of storing calculations is to use the elements of functional programming that have been built into C#.

A formula can be stored as a function, using one of the [`Func<T1,T2,...TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647.aspx) delegates.

```
var CalculationForX = new Func<double, double, double>( 
    (arg1, arg2) => arg1 * arg2
);
```

Here, `CalculationForX` specifies a function that takes two doubles, and returns a the product of the two doubles.  Then using for example `CalculationForX(5, 2)` returns 10.

---

So, a straightforward way to keep track of all the dependencies would be to store an object for each dependent variable, containing its formula and inputs.  These could be in the form of:

- an array of strings that contain the property names of a given object
- a `PropertyInfo` array
- an `Action<T1,T2>` delegate represents the actual property setter

Whenever you receive a property changed event, retrieve the calculation and the inputs for all variables that depend on it, and update the target values.

(It's funny to me that you asked this question, as I asked a quite similar one yesterday on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/171526/50958).)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I'll take a look into this. Did you end up using F# like the person that answered your question suggested?

Comment: @user1594138 I didn't -- I'd like to try it out, but not sure I have time to learn it well enough for my current project.

Comment: Hey dbaseman, F# is a blast! :) Take a look at this link: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/123830/functional-cells-a-spreadsheet-in-f/ - Everything is super easy once you understand F#, creating a new function is as simple as: "| Fun("MAX",ps) -> ps |> evalAll |> List.max " - Using this codebase. Or | Fun("ABS", [value]) -> if (eval value)>0.0M then eval value else -(eval value) - These functions work, though I don't know if they are done in the optimum way, I am just starting. Anyway, thought I'd share. Are you creating your system for yourself, a single person employer or big company?

Comment: Oh forgot to say, those functions are simply added under the "evaluate" function in the inner "eval" function.

Comment: @user1594138 my application is for a big company.  That is a sweet link, thanks.  It's a great starting point actually, I'm going to see if I can't apply that approach to my project.

Comment: yeah no problem. I was wondering though, with just a yes or no question. If it's possible to run the parser just once, and have it connect everything together, so that when cells need updating they can just directly call their functions, and use their values. Without having to evaluate some strings or something again and again and again? I didn't 100% understand your answer for the C# solution so I'm not sure what the answer is for C# or F#. I'm asking because I don't want to evaluate again and again. continued...

Comment: otherwise the only option would be to write code that writes code, that then gets compiled. I'm basically just looking for a very efficient
way for the computer to manage variables/cells. Maybe premature optimization, but I won't regret it later. My application involved such very heavy incrementation, where the input data changes millions of times per run.

Sorry for the endless questions, feel free to not answer :P

Comment: hmm I'm not sure if you can see this anymore. Doesn't look like you get updated. Since it doesn't suggest your name. But anyway I think I've solved it. I think its what you said. Basically evaluate the function seperately. That is store it in a different place than int he input values. Then for the cell value you combine them. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1594138 no prob, glad if I could help in any way.  My answer was for C#, as I really don't know enough F# to tackle this difficult of a task.  If speed is the main concern, I think using a two-way directed acyclic graph is best, so that when a variable/formula changes, you can quickly look up the values of all inputs, and crawl down the other way to update all dependent variables.   And like you said, store the formulas in a lookup somewhere.  (in C# it could be useful to use Expressions in the form of `Expression<Delegate>`, as that way you can retrieve the formula as a string)

Comment: @user1594138 email me if you like, dbaseman at gmail dot com.  Since we're both working on this, it might be useful for us to continue trading notes.

Comment: Actually I think I am just going to create a code-generator. I will be working only in code anyways, so generating code every time I need to add / remove cells doesn't hurt at all. By the way, here is another spreadsheet example: http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17472#254239 - This one is from the F# sample pack. Thanks for the email suggestion but I'm pretty much done, I just have to change implementation from spreadsheet evaluation, to generating F# code, and that code itself won't have any parsing and such. Just the generator.